# AJAX automatic file upload in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

So I fill a row into the database and then I'd need to upload a PDF/XML file. This should happen without any user interaction. The script would know what the filename is and where the file is located.

Is there any way to do this? Please empty your thoughts into the answer box!

Comment: 1: You can edit your post to put your notes in. 2: did you searched the web? 3: What have you tried so far? 4: Can you give any example code?

Comment: If you're wanting to upload a file from the users file system without them specifically selecting the file using an `<input type="file"/>`, then you can't.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Security model would preclude you from doing this.  If this were possible, it would mean that any server can read any file on your computer.

Comment: @Matt your edit says _do not_ but OP first comment says _do_!

Comment: voting to close as not constructive. it should be impossible, everything else would be criminal.

Comment: @andyb: Whooooooooops. Thanks :P

Comment: I do not think PHP is required, this more liky JavaScript question, correct me if I mistaken

Comment: Why are you guys so negative about this? Wow, even a downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparently uploading a file to a server without any kind of user interaction would be a huge security hole, and is not possible on any browser I know of. The only solution I see would be writing a Firefox extension, or maybe a Greasemonkey script the user would need to install beforehand.

Comment: I guess I'm going to write an extension to firefox then. Hope this wont be too hard :/

Comment: Perhaps you could detail what you are trying to do it for, there's almost certainly a better way to do the task, most likely in a different program (create an application that does it or something).

Comment: So after I have filled a row in a MySQL database, we would need to upload a recepit which is a PDF or an XML file. We would know based on the info we just filled into the database exactlu where the file would be located on the disk, and what the filename would be. Then this just needs to grab the file and upload it, without the user needing to do a thing but watch the progressbar (my coworkers are idiots :))